# How can I easily identify double-counted records in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with data that looks like this:

```
CustomerID                                                  | Exception Category

1000                                                         A1
1000                                                         A1
1001                                                         A2
1002                                                         A1
1000                                                         A3
1002                                                         A2
1003                                                         A1
```

In summary, a customer ID could have, in theory one or more exception labels - across c. 750,000 records, 
there are only five exception labels - A1 to A5.

I am trying to summarise the unique IDs falling into each bucket in a summary table, but the issue I have is with double-counting, as the same ID could fulfil the exception requirements for more than one exception, i.e. 1000 is an exception based on A1 as well as A3 criteria, as shown above.

Essentially, I'd like my output to look like this:

```
CustomerID                                    Exception Class Count    | Exception Category

1000                                                      2               A1
1000                                                      2               A3
1001                                                      1               A2
1002                                                      3               A1
1002                                                      3               A2
1002                                                      3               A3
```

As an explanation - customer ID 1000 falls into two categories of exceptions - A1 and A3, which is represented in the count(2) and the exceptions follow as individual entries in the third column. As can be seen in the original table, 1000 was marked against A1 twice, because the customer hit that exception category on two different dates - I'm fine for the duplicate row to be removed, and don't care which one gets removed as long as I don't lose the fact that 1000 fulfilled the A1 exception category (at some point in time).

Thanks again!

Comment: With that sample table data, what is the expected result?

Comment: Have you looked at `GROUP BY`? `PIVOT`would allow you to produce a cross tabulation of case against exception category.

Comment: expecting output is not quite clear. Please mention the expected output based on the sample data shared.

Comment: Hi - apologies my expected results table wasn't clear, I will add this below. I have looked at GROUP BY / HAVING, but it isn't helping me. Let me add the expected output below.

Comment: had issues in updating the expected output in my comment (still new to S/O :D), so have gone back and updated my original post. Thanks all.

Comment: There is no date in your table, so your explanation doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yes I know there is no date in my table, I had only included what is relevant. I was trying to explain that the reason you see 1000 - A1 twice is because the A1 may have been applied on different dates (which you can't see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With COUNT() window function:

```
select 
  CustomerID,
  count(*) over (partition by CustomerID) [Exception Class Count],
  [Exception Category]
from (
  select distinct CustomerID, [Exception Category]
  from tablename  
) t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=784f1c605c074b99768110e593570136).
Results (for your sample data):

```
> CustomerID | Exception Class Count | Exception Category
> ---------: | --------------------: | :-----------------
>       1000 |                     2 | A1                
>       1000 |                     2 | A3                
>       1001 |                     1 | A2                
>       1002 |                     2 | A1                
>       1002 |                     2 | A2                
>       1003 |                     1 | A1
```

Comment: Great - the sample data looks good, will run and feed back - thanks!

Comment: Worked perfectly - thanks very much! Learnt something new today as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this  -

**Sample Table and Data**

```
declare @data table
(
 CustomerID int,
 ExceptionCategory varchar(5)
 )


Insert into @data
(CustomerID, ExceptionCategory) 
values
(1000,'A1'),
(1000,'A1'),
(1001,'A2'),
(1002,'A1'),
(1000,'A3'),
(1002,'A2'),
(1002,'A3'),
(1003,'A1')
```

**Query**

```
;With cte (CustomerId, ExceptionClassCount)
as
(
select CustomerId, Count(distinct ExceptionCategory) ExceptionClassCount
From  @data
Group by CustomerId
) 
select distinct  cte.CustomerId, cte.ExceptionClassCount, d.ExceptionCategory
from cte join @data d on cte.CustomerId = d.CustomerId
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much Mukesh - please can you take a look at my updated query, where I have tried to represent my expected output, and put in an explanation?

Comment: @SQLGIT_GeekInTraining - try above query to get the desired result.

Comment: thanks, but as you can see - 1000 is repeating twice in the first two rows. I'm only interested in one row, which tells me that 1000 has fulfilled EC A1. The customer ID should appear as many times as the exceptionclasscount. so if there's two, I just want to see two entries for 1000.

Comment: @SQLGIT_GeekInTraining - Try now with the above-updated query. I hope this is what you needed.

Comment: @SQLGIT_GeekInTraining - You are most welcome , If this solution helps you. You can upvote the solution.